# JSONHTTPClient.m - "use of undeclared identifier UIApplication" build error (line 387)

Tags: objective-c, build-error, jsonmodel

I just added [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) to my projected, according to instructions:

1. Download the JSONModel repository as a zip file or clone it
2. Copy the JSONModel sub-folder into your Xcode project
3. Link your app to SystemConfiguration.framework

tried to build, and... build error!

***"use of undeclared identifier UIApplication" build error (line 387)***

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in here :

To fix it I added this , just below ***#import "JSONHTTPClient.h"*** (in JSONHTTPClient.m):

> #ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
>
> #import < UIKit/UIKit.h> //<-delete the space, I couldn't write it without
>
> #endif

Answer (score 1):

add `@import UIKit;` in `JSONHTTPClient.h` file